# PHP/jQuery quiz

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I am looking to create an online quiz/test for my website.

I've read up quite a lot and I also found this very useful post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231808/php-php-open-source-quiz-exam-script

I am currently trying the top one:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpq/?_test=b

Which I cannot get to work:
http://quiz.easy2dev.com/admin/login.php?Page=Login

```
    $UserName = "Admin";        //User name for logon into Quest
    $Password = "Password";     //Password for logon
    $Tile = "quiz";         //Enter the title of your site
```

So what I wanted to know was if anyone knew somewhere I could grab an open source quiz/test.

In PHP/jQuery and it doesn't have to use MySQL as I have only just started using databases but I know it would be better to manage in the long run if database driven.

The quiz I would like there to be instant feedback when the 'Next' button is clicked, this is why I thought of jQuery.

http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/jQuiz/

The quiz above is fantastic, and more than ideal, but I haven't a clue how to show the answer and a summary underneath the question when the next button is clicked, instead of it going directly to the next question. It would be my preferable choice if anyone can guide me on how I can go about it.

Regards,

John.

Comment: That quiz is awful... and half the answers are wrong...

Comment: @cbuckley: You don't put your javascript in a `<javascript>` element?

Comment: All I wanted was the quiz lol, not the questions in them. It's sorted now, glad this was closed as it was fairly old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have each page be self-referencing, so that before you click an answer it has a button that says "Select Answer" and then when the page refreshes with the answer being displayed, a "Continue Quiz" button is now the only button visible.

I think you are over thinking the complexity of this.

Just use forms, _POST (and maybe SESSION) variables and then at the end of the quiz have a chunk of code devoted to writing the results to a database (if you want it saved).